# How to get hidden value from multiple input text?

Tags: php

I'm creating a small program to input sales target for multiple salesman. How to get salesman id only if target is not empty.

I'm using array input type hidden to store salesman id.  But everytime i tried to get salesman id whose target field not empty, it printed all salesman id.

This is the input:

```php
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="send"><br/>
  <?
      $getSales = "SELECT sales_id, sales_name FROM SALESMAN";
      $execSales = odbc_exec($conn,$getSales);
      while(odbc_fetch_row($execSales)) {
         $idSales = odbc_result($execSales,"sales_id");
         $nameSales = odbc_result($execSales,"sales_name");

         ?>
         <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="salesid[]" id="salesid">
            <td><input type="text" name="target[]" id="target"></td>
         </tr>
         <?
         }
    ?>
</form>
```

This form will result something like this

```
Sales Id   || Target     |
--------------------------
SLS0001    || |______30| | ==> 30 for sls0001
SLS0002    || |________| | ==> no target for sls0002
SLS0003    || |______10| | ==> 10 for sls0002
```

to get the salesid with target not empty,  i create this

```
foreach (array_filter($_POST['salesid']) as $key => $salesId)
{
    echo $salesId.'<br/>';
}
```

What i expect for the result is

```
SLS0001
SLS0003
```

but the result is

```
SLS0001
SLS0002
SLS0003
```

How to get the expected result? Thank you.

Comment: fyi, `<input>` inside `<tr>` is invalid. And `id`s should be unique. Also, `<table>` and `</table>` would be nice.

Comment: "to  get the salesid with target not empty, i create this".... But none of the code which follows that statement has anything to do with the target field. It doesn't make any use of it. It's unclear why you expected it to do anything like what you've stated. You'd need to check the content of the relevant target field before you decide whether to echo.

Comment: I'm sorry if its not clear. I tried my best. But Thank you, i already find the solution below..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you need to be checking if `$_POST['target']` is empty, not `salesid`.

You can use array_combine in conjunction with array_filter to achieve this result. See more info on array_combine here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

`array_combine($_POST['salesid'], $_POST['target'])` will give you an array like:

```
array(
 'SLS0001' => '30',
 'SLS0002' => '',
 'SLS0003' => '10'
);
```

Then applying array_filter it will give you the correct result.

```
// makes salesid your key, and target your value, array_filter will filter out empties from target
foreach (array_filter(array_combine($_POST['salesid'], $_POST['target'])) as $salesid => $target)
{
    echo $salesid.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (array_filter($_POST['salesid']) as $key => $salesId)
{
    if (!/* here you use condition for is empty or null */)
        echo $salesId.'<br/>';
}
```